# Type mismatch, expected: CodedInputStream, actual: FileInputStream

Tags: java, scala, protocol-buffers

**val persons = Person()

persons.mergeFrom(new FileInputStream("path_of_file"))**

- Person is a scala class generated using protobuf compiler in scala.
- I just wanted to read a pdub(a binary file) and append some more
  content in it and then write it back to disk.
- following this link https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial, its in java but for my case i am trying in scala.

**Error** : Type mismatch, expected: CodedInputStream, actual: FileInputStream

Comment: Well ... The error message is quite self-explaining, isn't it? You have to provide a `CodedInputStream`. Maybe you want to do `persons.mergeFrom(CodedInputStream.newInstance(new FileInputStream("path_of_file")))`?

Comment: thanks it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a CodedInputStream.

Change:

```
persons.mergeFrom(new FileInputStream("path_of_file"))
```

To:

```
persons.mergeFrom(CodedInputStream.newInstance(new FileInputStream("path_of_file")))
```